# How to define a "composite type" with the "group" constructor?

Tags: customize, defcustom

I am trying to define a composite type using the "group" compositor (see [Elisp Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html#Composite-Types), section "Composite Types"). Previously, I managed to define a composite type with the "list" constructor.

The Elisp manual tells that these constructors ("group" and "list") are similar. I get a weird result in the "Customize interface" and an error message displayed in the echo area.

```
Operate on all settings in this buffer:
[ Revert... ] [ Apply ] [ Apply and Save ]

Hide
```

#### Sample code

```
(defcustom group '(1 2 3)
    "here, give a description of the user option."
    :type '(group integer integer integer))
```

I noticed the message "*custom-variable-value-create: Bad format*" in the "Messages" buffer.

The manual should be clarified. Someone had the same issue one decade ago: "[No doc for `group' in custom :type](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-pretest-bug/2007-06/msg00067.html)".

.

Comment: I think `:type' `group' is bugged. I just submitted [bug #33566](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33566) for this. (BTW, that someone was me, but it's not really the same bug, I think.)